# Sfl4j and java 8: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Tags: java, java-8, slf4j

I have a very expensive operation to generate a debug message and I want to avoid for it to be generated each time.

So I use this:

```
log.debug("{}", () -> expensive()); //gives the target type must be a functional interface
```

I defined:

```
private String expensive(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    aLongList.forEach( (element) -> sb.append(element));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think SLF4J hast support for lazy message ***parameter*** construction, just for lazy ***message*** construction (using message formatting).

But you could use something like this:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()){
  log.debug(expensive());
}
```

Comment: It goes against sonar rule that's why I'm looking for alternatives :(

Comment: In the end I switched to log4j2 and it provides the interface I'm looking for!. Thanks for signaling that it was slf4j fault